# Skip OnActionExecuted execution

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, actionfilterattribute, onactionexecuted

I made an ActionFilterAttribute that has the OnActionExecuted method implemented. That means, it runs after the Action method.
But, in certain condition, I want the OnActionExecuted to not be executed.

How do I, from the Action method, prevent the ActionFilter from being executed?

For now, I have made this:

On the Action method:

```
RouteData.Values.Add("CancelActionFilter", true);
```

And on the ActionFilter.OnActionExecuted():

```
if (filterContext.RouteData.Values["CancelActionFilter"] != null)
{
    return;
}
```

But I think that may exist a more elegant approach.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OnActionExecuted is called inside the InvokeActionMethodFilter method in the ControllerActionInvoker class.

Inside this method there's nothing to prevent the action of been executed. I think yours is a good solution.

[Code of ControllerActionInvoker class](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/1acb241299a8#src/System.Web.Mvc/ControllerActionInvoker.cs)